# beforeShowDay Datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am in need to call two functions or to figure out how to merge two functions that interact with Jquery UI Datepicker. One that highlights certain dates the other that disables dates. I have it working properly if I only call one function. I need help on how to merge them.

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[


        /* create an array of days which need to be disabled */
        var disabledDays = ["2011-5-21","2011-5-22"];

        var overrideDays = ["2011-5-15","2011-5-16"];


          function getAvailableDays(date){
            var dateAsString = date.getFullYear().toString() + "-" + (date.getMonth()+1).toString() + "-" + date.getDate();
            var result = jQuery.inArray( dateAsString, disabledDays ) ==-1 ? [true] : [false];

            return result
          }

          function setOverrideDays(date){
            var dateAsString = date.getFullYear().toString() + "-" + (date.getMonth()+1).toString() + "-" + date.getDate();
            var result = jQuery.inArray( dateAsString, overrideDays ) == -1 ? [true] : [true,"test2"];
                return result
          }
        //]]>
        </script>


        <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            $("#datepicker").datepicker({
                    dateFormat:'mm/dd/yy',
                    beforeShowDay: getAvailableDays,

                    minDate: 0
            });


        });</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this:

```
function setDays(date) {
    var dateAsString = date.getFullYear().toString() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1).toString() + "-" + date.getDate();
    if(jQuery.inArray(dateAsString, overrideDays) != -1){
        return [true, "test2"];
    } 
    if(jQuery.inArray(dateAsString, disabledDays) != -1){
        return [false];
    }
    return [true];
}
```

**[Example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/Kuer6/)**